# Making both divs responsive

Tags: html, css

I have two div tags. One automatically adjusts the height to content. The other one has fixed height(This one contains gmaps.js plugin). The one that has fixed height contains Google maps, and I have to add the height, if I don't it just doesn't show the map.

How could I make them have same height all the time, even when resizing the window.

JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ntq3xp6b/

**THE CODE FROM JS FIDDLE**

```
<div class="left">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left{
    display:block;
    width:49.9%;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
}

.right{
    display:block;
    width:49.9%;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    height:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a parent div with a specific `height`. Then set the `height` of each `.box` to 100%, with a `min-height` of 300px to ensure the Google Maps will fit.

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
}
.box {
  width: 49.9%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.box.left {
  background-color: red;
}
.box.right {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left box">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="right box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, for some reason the gmaps.js plugin has to have the height defined in px. If it is in % it doesn't show the map.

Comment: I had no idea you were using a plugin. Please include that in your original question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also add a top and bottom padding?

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
}
.box {
  width: 49.9%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  padding-top:10px
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
.box.left {
  background-color: red;
}
.box.right {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left box">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div class="right box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try the [jQuery matchHeight](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/) -plugin.

```
 $(function() {
    $('.box').matchHeight();
});
```

It will give the boxes fixed height of the tallest of them. The height value will update when the window is resized.